# Solving $\frac{\sqrt{r+1}-\sqrt{r-1}}{\sqrt{r+1}+\sqrt{r-1}}=\log_2\left(|x-2|+|x+2|\right)-\frac{11}{9}$, where $r=\frac{1+x^2}{2x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, logarithms

*The problems in my sophomore workbook are marked with three colors that signify how hard is the marked problem: green for D and C, yellow for B and A and red for advanced students. All problems are also ordered from the easiest to the hardest.*

*This problem is marked red and appears last in the section of logarithmic problems, which means that it's the hardest logarithmic problem in the whole workbook. I know what its solution is (there are solutions at the end of the workbook), but I'd like to see how do we arrive at it.*

*I wrote the solution here, but it's hidden until it's hovered over. I don't want to spoil fun to those who want to find it by themselves.*

> Find the value(s) of $x$ when the left-hand side is equal to the right-hand side.
>
> $$\frac{\sqrt{\dfrac{1+x^2}{2x}+1}\;-\;\sqrt{\dfrac{1+x^2}{2x}-1}}{\sqrt{\dfrac{1+x^2}{2x}+1}\;+\;\sqrt{\dfrac{1+x^2}{2x}-1}}=\log_2(|x-2|+|x+2|)-\frac{11}{9}$$

**The solution is**

> $$x_1=\frac{7}{9},x_2=\frac{9}{7}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

Since
$$\sqrt{\frac{1+x^2}{2x}\pm1}= \sqrt{(x\pm1)^2\over 2x} = {|x\pm1|\over \sqrt{2x}}$$
we have 
$$\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1+x^2}{2x}+1}-\sqrt{\frac{1+x^2}{2x}-1}}{\sqrt{\frac{1+x^2}{2x}+1}+\sqrt{\frac{1+x^2}{2x}-1}}={|x+1|-|x-1|\over |x+1|+|x-1|}$$

---

Let $f(x)=|x+2|+|x-2| $, then $f(x)=4$ for $x\in[-2,2]$ and for $|x|>2$ we have $f(x)>4$.

So, for $|x|>2$ we have $\log_2f(x)-11/9>7/9$ so we have $|x+1|>8|x-1|$

a) if $x>2$ we get $x<9/7$ a contradiction and

b) if $x<-2$ we get $x>7/9$ a contradiction again.

So we are left with the $|x|\leq 2$ so we have $$|x+1|=8|x-1|$$

Can you finish?

Comment: I'll give it a go.

Comment: To hard? @Hanlon

Answer (score 2):

Hint: multiplying the left-hand side's numerator and denominator by the numerator obtains $r-\sqrt{r^2-1}$, and this is just $\exp -|\ln x|$. So we want to solve $\exp -|\ln x|+\frac{11}{9}=\log_2 (|x-2|+|x+2|)$.

Comment: This is not true, put $x= 2$ and you will see.

Comment: @ChristianF Sorry; fixed.

Comment: This is stil not true. try $x=1/2

Comment: @ChristianF Sorry; I had to go offline for a few hours.

Answer (score 2):

Simplify the LHS:
$$\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1+x^2}{2x}+1}-\sqrt{\frac{1+x^2}{2x}-1}}{\sqrt{\frac{1+x^2}{2x}+1}+\sqrt{\frac{1+x^2}{2x}-1}}=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{(x+1)^2}{2x}}-\sqrt{\frac{(x-1)^2}{2x}}}{\sqrt{\frac{(x+1)^2}{2x}}+\sqrt{\frac{(x-1)^2}{2x}}}\overbrace{=}^{x>0}{|x+1|-|x-1|\over |x+1|+|x-1|}.$$
Hence:
$${|x+1|-|x-1|\over |x+1|+|x-1|}=\log_2(|x-2|+|x+2|)-\frac{11}{9}.$$
Consider the intervals:
$$x\in (0,1]: \qquad {2x\over 2}=\log_2 4-\frac{11}{9} \Rightarrow x=\frac79;\\
x\in (1,2]: \qquad {2\over 2x}=\log_2 4-\frac{11}{9} \Rightarrow x=\frac97;\\
x\in (2,+\infty): \qquad {2\over 2x}=\log_2 (2x)-\frac{11}{9} \Rightarrow \log_2x=\frac 1x+\frac29 \Rightarrow \emptyset, \text{because}:\\
\log_2x\ge 1>\frac{13}{18}\ge \frac 1x+\frac29, x\ge 2.$$